# Magento 2.3.3 Frontend Header and Mini Cart not loading issues

Tags: magento2minicart

I am new to magento. I am change the Forget password email attempt time and save the changes in backend. But my changes are not reflected so i flush and clean the cache via command. After clean & flushing, my site frontend header was not loaded. In the header login , signup links and my mini cart also not showing.

I tried the following commands, but nothing will happen to me.

1. php bin/magento cache:clean
2. php bin/magento cache:flush
3. php bin/magento indexer:reindex
4. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Can anyone help me to resolve this issues?

Comment: If my answer help you, please accept it. So it will help other in community as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try once again using below command.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                        // 644 permission for files
 find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                        // 755 permission for directory

sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend sudo rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml sudo rm -rf pub/static/_cache sudo rm -rf var/cache sudo rm -rf var/composer_home sudo rm -rf var/generation sudo rm -rf var/generated sudo rm -rf var/page_cache sudo rm -rf var/view_preprocessed sudo rm -rf var/log sudo rm -rf var/report sudo rm -rf generated/code/ sudo rm -rf generated/metadata/

php bin/magento maintenance:enable
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento maintenance:disable
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/media/ pub/static/
```

Comment: Hi Bhavesh, Thanks for your reply. I did the things you mentioned in the above. but its not working. Can you help me ?

Comment: @MZP First set the developer mode then again run above command line by line, Also, what is your magento version?

Comment: I changed the mode from default mode to developer mode and ran the above commands you mentioned. My magento version is 2.3.3. Also in my terminal i am not installing sudo. So i run the rm command without sudo. Still not working

Comment: Thanks for you help its working now.

Comment: @MZP If my answer help you, please accept it. So it will help other in community as well.