# Magento 2.4 not working

Tags: magento2, installation

I have installed Magento 2.4.3 it says not found on
`http://127.0.0.1/magento2/` & works on `http://127.0.0.1/magento2/pub/` but does not render the proper page.

How to fix this in macOS?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Use a virtual machine or docker for working with Magento on Mac. Magento is not officially supported on Mac or Windows

Comment: follow this step - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/354077/3723

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution if showing version name in CSS path

**like : pub/static/version323334/**

then run this query in my SQL

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (path, value) 
VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;
after that clear the config cache



bin/magento cache:clean config
```

For more info please look into it, it may help you.
[A lot of js.map file not found after upgrade to Magento 2.4.3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/354095/a-lot-of-js-map-file-not-found-after-upgrade-to-magento-2-4-3/354176#354176)

if still issue exit then you may try this one as it's for windows issue but you can try may got any luck.

window 2.3 not working into local host
solution for that
**#/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Validator.php:139**

```
foreach ($directories as $directory) {
    // Add this line
    $realDirectory = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($directory);
    // and replace `$directory` with `$realDirectory`
    if (0 === strpos($realPath, $realDirectory)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please make below changes and then check,**

- Rename `.htaccess` file
- Move the `.htaccess` file from the `pub` folder to your Magento root folder
  (Magento_243)
- Copy the `index.php` file of `2.4.2` to your Magento folder (Magento_243)
- Add below records using insert query in `core_config table`,

  **path ->** `web/unsecure/base_media_url` **value ->** http://127.0.0.1/Magento_243/pub/media/
  **path ->** `web/unsecure/base_static_url` **value ->** http://127.0.0.1/Magento_243/pub/static/
  **path ->** `web/secure/base_static_url` **value ->** http://127.0.0.1/Magento_243/pub/static/
  **path ->** `web/secure/base_media_url` **value ->** http://127.0.0.1/Magento_243/pub/media/
- Apply query in `core_config_data` `INSERT INTO core_config_data (path, value) VALUES ('dev/static/sign', 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;`

**Hope it helps.**